# How do I pipe dmenu output into a command?

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I'm experimenting with dmenu and ran into a problem.

I want to create a .bash_history menu of previous commands, select one and then have it either run in my terminal. Here is what I have so far.

```
cat ~/.bash_history | dmenu -l 20
```

When this is run from the terminal, it will echo out my choice. When I run this from a script, it outputs my entire bash history.

[The command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4duU.png)

[The script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZMZ8.png)

Comment: Could you add an example to the post?

Comment: I've updated the post with some pictures

Comment: It's not enough to see what happens with `dmenu` and `cat`.

Comment: I'm sorry, Im not sure what else to add? When the cat output of bash history is piped into dmenu, dmenu opens with each line of the file and I select one

Comment: Cannot replicate. What is the script exactly? And why doesn't the title reflect the *current* problem (i.e. different behavior: command line vs script)? It seems "piping `dmenu` output into a command" may be the *next* problem.

Answer (score 1):

The below script appears to bring up dmenu and return the selection to stdout in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/.bash_history | dmenu -l 20
exit
```

I got brought here as a top google search for the question header: "How do I pipe dmenu output into a command?". I was looking for a simple script to execute selections from dmenu in the bash shell. The following appears to work in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash 
read thing2execute <<< $(cat ~/.bash_history | dmenu -l 20)
$thing2execute
exit
```

There is also a much more complex general purpose script to do this available on the suckless.org sit here:
https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/scripts/dmenu_run_with_command_history/

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of Googling, I found a solution similar to Mike's answer, but a bit simpler. You could use $() to achieve your task

```
 $(cat ~/.bash_history | dmenu -l 20)
```

This basically allows you to get the output from dmenu and execute it as the next command